# AWS System Manager RunRemoteScript, the script was downloaded but not executed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I set up a Windows instance on Azure, configured it as a multicloud environment on AWS System Manager, and confirmed the connection was successful.

In the Windows instance, I set up Python and an SSM agent that were setup correctly to connect to AWS System Management. The IAM profile used on this instance has full permission to access the S3 bucket.

Then I'm using AWS System Manager > Run Command and setting up the following configuration:

- Document: AWS-RunRemoteScript
- Version: 1
- Source type: S3
- Source info: {"path":"https://my-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/update_cfg.py"}
- Command: update_cfg GOT_NEW_UPDATE GOT_NEW_UPDATE2
- Working Directory: C:\Users\khanhnd0408\Downloads
- Target selection: Choose instances manually -> tick on my instance.
- Disable output log to S3
- RUN

The status is successful, and I found the downloaded file from S3 in the working directory, but the script is not running as expected.

[image]

Run command result:
[image]

I also checked the output log; it was just empty on output and error.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
writer = open("dummy", "w")
writer.write("dummyyyy\n")
writer.close()

import os
import sys

def replace_text_in_file(file_path, old_text, new_text):
    try:
        # Read the file
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            file_content = file.read()

        # Replace the old text with the new text
        modified_content = file_content.replace(old_text, new_text)

        # Write the modified content back to the file
        with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
            file.write(modified_content)

        print(f"Text replacement in {file_path} completed successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

# Usage example
cwd = os.getcwd()
file_path = os.path.join(cwd, 'nginx.conf')
old_text = sys.argv[1]
new_text = sys.argv[2]

replace_text_in_file(file_path, old_text, new_text)
```

Basicly, this code looks for args[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPkVY.png) text, then replaces it with args[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBTL5.png). It also creates a dummy file when the script runs (just make sure the script runs), but all of my expectations are not working.
Note: The nginx.conf file was placed in the same directory as the downloaded Python code.

I also update the PATH environment to include the Python directory and confirm it is callable on Command Prompt and PowerShell.

Is there anything wrong with my configuration?

Thanks in advance.